# Error in query sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

i am getting an error in this Query

like this

**select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause**

i have  declared the  parameters to

```
DECLARE         
 @Cnt1   INT,
EmpName varchar(50)
SELECT @Cnt1 =COUNT(EmpID),@EmpName=Employeefirstname FROM Employee WHERE  EmpID='12'
```

pls let me know  how  can i solve this issue.

Thanks
Prince

Answer (score 4):

Every field in the `SELECT` clause must be an aggregated value or be contained in a `GROUP BY` clause. So the fix would be:

```
SELECT @Cnt1 =COUNT(EmpID),@EmpName=Employeefirstname FROM Employee
WHERE EmpID='12' GROUP BY Employeefirstname
```